# Set any white pixels to transparent in ImageMagick using a threshold?

Tags: imagemagick

Using ImageMagick, I want to find any pixels that are white and make them transparent. I'm thinking the key is *-threshold* but I can't work out how to change a white pixel to transparent using *-threshold*. Any suggestions most appreciated.

Comment: Without threshold: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9155377/set-transparent-background-using-imagemagick-and-commandline-prompt

Answer (score 15):

```
convert input.png -fuzz 10% -transparent white output.png
```

Note that the order of the arguments is important - `-fuzz` must come before `-transparent`.

Comment: the docs says "-fuzz" is only good for GIFs (they prbbly mean indexed color images).  https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/masking/#semi-trans

Answer (score 4):

Would something like this work?

```
convert input.jpg -fuzz 5% -fill to_color -opaque from_color output.jpg
```