# ImageMagick extend canvas with transparent background

Tags: background, imagemagick, png, transparency

```
convert input.png -extent 100x100 -gravity center -background white output.png
```

If the input is 50x50 the surrounding background is white. Can I somehow set this to transparent without declaring any color within input as transparent?

Answer (score 130, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
convert               \
      input.png       \
     -background none \
     -gravity center  \
     -extent 100x100  \
      output.png
```

***Note well:*** The order of the parameters is significant! (To convince yourself, just put `-background none` at the end of the parameters instead of the start...)

---

*Updated:* Thanks to @jesmith who noticed that the commandline I originally provided does no longer work as intended. More recent versions of `convert` additionally require that the `-gravity center` is called *before* `-extent 100x100`. (This was one of the changes introduced to one ImageMagick's most recent versions [at the time of originally writing this answer]).

Comment: Indeed the order is important, and you got it wrong! You need to put -gravity before -extent, or it will have no effect. Try -gravity SouthEast to see what I mean.

Comment: @noɥʇʎPʎzɐɹC: Thx -- fixed.

Answer (score 10):

Kurt's note is ironically spot on, order matters greatly. Kurt's command results in `gravity` not being applied to the `extent`, so the transparent 'border' will all be to the bottom and/or right of the image.

Moving `gravity` before `extent` will correctly create equal transparent 'borders' on all applicable sides.

> convert  input.jpg  -background none -gravity Center -extent 100x50 
>   output.png

Comment: **+1** and thanks for your additional answer pointing out the now required command line order for `-gravity center`. I hadn't seen it, nor @jesmith's comment earlier, though he had pointed it out already in May '13.