# Set background color while converting from images with transparency

Tags: imagemagick-convert

I am `convert`ing PostScript files to PNG, which works as expected, however I'd like the resulting output files to have a background of `snow1` anywhere the original files have transparency.  [This resource](https://imagemagick.org/script/convert.php) would lead me to believe I could use `-background` for that, however it doesn't seem to work. I suppose I could create an image consisting of only `snow1` and merge the two together, but that approach seems a bit hacky.

Example: `convert foo.ps -background snow1 foo.png`

Comment: The solution posted here gives the result I was looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46467523/how-to-change-picture-background-color-using-imagemagick#comment118564791_46474064