# node.js: Is it possible to replace a certain color in an image with transparent?

Tags: javascript, node.js, image-processing

I am trying to remove the white background of an image (similar to maxOS's Preview's Instant Alpha tool).

Comment: This seems more like a https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ question

Comment: Maybe use image magick? Command line program, there's some node wrapper on npm. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9155377/set-transparent-background-using-imagemagick-and-commandline-prompt