# Convert grayscale image to progressive black plus transparency?

Tags: shell, raster, gdal, imagemagick-convert

I have a grey scale image, from which I wish to convert all grey pixels into half transparent pixels, and white ones into transparent pixels.

**How could I process a grey scale raster image via shell ?**

Input :
[image]

Output (here made via Gimp):
[image]

---

Current Gimp process via GUI:

1. GIMP 2.6 > Load your shaded relief image (....shaded.tif : are grayscale)
   or a screenshoot of your shaded relief (screenshot : RGB colors)
2. Force it to be RGB: Gimp > Image > Mode > RGB, click.
3. Delete the grey : Colors > "color to alpha" pop up > uncheck "preview", click on the horizontal color rectangle > "Color to alpha color picker" pop up> bottom right corner, click on the icon eyes dropper > choice you color of to delete (some grey pixel in a flat plain) > validate.
4. Delete an other color (white, black background) > same.
5. File > save as > ProjectName_relief_whitened.png (to keep transparency)

Comment: Do you have some keywords to suggest.

Comment: How about: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4393949/set-any-white-pixels-to-transparent-in-imagemagick

Comment: @Scony: This seems a good catch !

Comment: After an hard time, I finally found something solid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[note: SO images display, and image background CSS makes hard to see the subtile differences between files.]*

Given the following gray scale `input.png` :

[image]

1a. To make black pixels of this image transparent and linearly keep the white pixels as they are, run this command:

```
convert source.png -alpha copy -fx '#fff' result.png
```

1b. To make white pixels transparent and linearly keep the black as they are, use:

```
convert source.png -alpha copy -channel alpha -negate +channel result.png
```

**Manual:**

- **convert** – is the ImageMagic command (one of several)
- **source.png** – is the greyscale source image.
- **-alpha copy** – it copy contents of the previous file into the alpha channel.
- **-channel alpha** – it specify that following operators only should affect the alpha channel.
- **-negate** – it invert the current channel (channel alpha).
- **+channel** – Specify that following operators only affect the opposite channel. For us, it switch focus from the alpha channel, to the color channel. (color channel is initially the default)
- **-fx '#000'** – Replace current channel (for us, the color channel) contents with black pixels, so the end result actually fully depends on the alpha channel. If not included, all semi-transparent pixels in generated image will retain colors, from #FFF (white) to #000 (black).

**Result of 1b:**

[image]

**Wiping out plains:**
An additional processing could wipe out most of the flat plains, which appears around greys (`#DDDDDD`) with opacity:~50%. This could be done by :

```
convert input.png -fuzz 8% -transparent "#DDDDDD" grey_no.8pc.png
convert grey_no.8pc.png -alpha copy -channel alpha -negate +channel result.grey_no.png
```

so the plains avoid an useless `#DDDDDD, opacity:50%` overlay.

[image]

**See also:**

1. ImageMagick options: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php

Comment: Great answer. I think you can use `-evaluate set 100%` rather than `-fx '#fff'` and it runs about 4x faster.